# how can I convert the contents of one column in a CSV file from HTML tags to Markdown

Tags: markdown

I am trying to move data from one system to another. My export from the source system includes HTML tags in a text field. My target system does not render these tags, as it requires Markdown, and not HTML for formatting text.

I need something that will take my CSV file and convert the codes in the column with the HTML codes to markdown so that I can then import into the target system.

Basically, read the file, find the content in a named column, and convert the HTML tags to Markdown, then save the results back in the same column.

TIA

I've looked at some online tools, but with them I either need to copy in just the block of text that I want converted (not an option given the volume) or the tools want to convert a full file from HTML to Markdown, not what I want to do.

Comment: Did you consider writing a script of to achieve your goal? Can you show some attemts, and also how the input and the desired output looks?

Comment: I am not a developer, so I was hoping for a solution that doesn't involve scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there aren't online tools that do this already as you said, using a simple python script should work. This converts HTML to markdown and writes it to the same CSV it read.

> pip install pandas html2text

```
import pandas as pd
from html2text import html2text

def convert_html_to_markdown(filename, column_name):
    # Load the data from the CSV file
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)

    # Convert the HTML in the specified column to Markdown
    df[column_name] = df[column_name].apply(html2text)

    # Save the updated DataFrame to the CSV file
    df.to_csv(filename, index=False)

# Example usage:
convert_html_to_markdown('data.csv', 'my_column')
```

Make sure to replace the `data.csv` and `my_column` values with the correct names

Comment: Thanks. I'll work with my developers to get this implemented